# Function with single parameter does not seem to run/return correctly

Tags: php, function

I've had a quick browse, and I'm hoping this isn't a duplicate, because as far as I can tell, my code looks correct and I've performed everything that is covered in other questions.

I have a function in an external file, which I include with PHP:

```
include("functions.php");
```

The contents of that file are as follows (condensed to one `if`):

```
function tidyWebsiteBrand($ukip_name) {
    if (strpos($ukip_name,"International") !== false) {
        $ukip_name = substr($ukip_name,0,-14);
    }
    return $ukip_name;
}
```

I think call that function in my code, with the parameter `$ukip_name`:

```
while ($bq = mysql_fetch_assoc($brand_query)) {
    $ukip_code = $bq['ukip_code'];
    $ukip_name = $bq['ukip_name'];
    tidyWebsiteBrand($ukip_name);
    ?>
    <option value="<?=$ukip_code?>"><?=$ukip_name?></option>
    <?php
}
```

However the `<option>` still displays the "pre-function" text, as opposed to the "post-function" text.

Expected result: `"Automotive Testing"`

Actual result: `"Automotive Testing International"`

Where am I going wrong?

Answer (score 4):

PHP is call-by-value with that parameter type. You need to do:

```
$ukip_name = tidyWebsiteBrand($ukip_name);
```

Comment: Thank you. For reference, in what instance(s) could I call a function without calling-by-value?

Answer (score 1):

```
tidyWebsiteBrand($ukip_name);
```

You're not assigning the return value to anything. Presumably it should be:

```
$ukip_name = tidyWebsiteBrand($ukip_name);
```

Answer (score 0):

You are running a function on $ukip_name but not saving the result.

```
    <option value="<?=$ukip_code?>"><?=tidyWebsiteBrand($ukip_name)?></option>
```